# What does $\langle2\rangle$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does $\langle2\rangle$ mean?

I encountered it in the context of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and it seemed most likely to mean something like $\{2^z:z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ from what I could deduce but I've been unable to find a reference to it.

Comment: It is the ideal of the $2$-adic rationals generated by $2$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 thanks; and does that correspond with my interpretation? I see ideals include the multiples of e.g. some integer which would imply $\{6,10,12,\ldots\}$ are also elements - the even numbers.

Comment: p.s. does the set I wrote have a name?

Comment: Context will tell. $\langle 2\rangle$ is some substructure generated by $2$. It could be either A) the multiplicative subgroup generated by $2$, B) the additive subgroup generated by $2$, C) an ideal (of a ring "obvious" from the context) generated by $2$. In the case of $\Bbb{Q}_2$ my instincts suggest that interpretation A is the most likely (the one you inferred also). This is because for B I would write $2\Bbb{Z}$ and for C I would write $2\Bbb{Z}_2$ (assuming that the ring of 2-adic integers is the ring whose ideals we would be interested in).

Comment: @Mathematician42 it would seem $\langle2\rangle$ contains $\{x:\lvert x\rvert_2\leq 1\}$ - is that correct?

Comment: I guess it might be possible to write $2^{\Bbb{Z}}$ for the multiplicative generated by $2$, but that could easily be confused with the powerset notation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the **general** answer; I now know how to interpret it both in general and this case. So in the context it would be $A=\{\ldots,2,4,8,\ldots\}$ (and incidentally it was you who wrote it)

Comment: In that case you should obviously give less weight to my opinion here. I didn't remember the occasion I used it, but anyway, the opinion I wrote here is clearly colored by my personal preferences. As is my past use.

Comment: $<2>$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $\mathbb Q_2$ containing $2$. It's usually referred to as *the subgroup generated by 2*.

Comment: The subgroups of $\mathbf Q_2^\times$.

Comment: @Mathematician42: It is not an ideal. There aren't so many ideals in a field.

Comment: @Bernard: You're right, I didn't really think that through.